# Windows 7 box joined to domain but unable to search domain locations for users

Tags: windows-7, active-directory

I've been experiencing an odd issue on a Windows 7 box joined to our Windows Server 2008 AD domain.

I've been trying to add a local admin to the box while logged as in my domain admin user. However, when I search for the user, it only shows the local users and not domain users. I've tried searching for locations but it doesn't even display the domain to search from.

Logging into the box as domain users works as it shows that it is joined to the domain.

Thanks in advance for any assistance...first time I've come across this!

Answer (score 1):

I ended up figuring it out:

For some reason somebody on the workstation had setup DNS to use systems other than our managed DNS servers. Even though it was able to resolve internal DNS entries, because it wasn't using our domain controllers for DNS this was not working.

Hopefully this will save somebody else a headache at some point in the future!